# Dead locking when accessing the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, deadlock

I have a C# application that works with data in a SQL Server table via stored procedures.
If 2 users execute a form copy at the same time the same procedure is executed where dead locking occurs
I got xml_deadlock_report in SQL Server under system_health. Here is what it looks like:

```
<deadlock>
 <victim-list>
  <victimProcess id="process10f2ea0188" />
 </victim-list>
 <process-list>
  <process id="process10f2ea0188" taskpriority="0" logused="7424" waitresource="PAGE: 5:1:24768207 " waittime="83419" ownerId="61921962" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2022-06-21T05:40:40.083" XDES="0x6d4f80d28" lockMode="S" schedulerid="5" kpid="2392" status="suspended" spid="69" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="1" lastbatchstarted="2022-06-21T05:40:40.143" lastbatchcompleted="2022-06-21T05:40:40.083" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.083" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="GKA" hostpid="12432" loginname="admin" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="61921962" currentdb="5" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673185824" clientoption2="128048">
   <executionStack>
    <frame procname="CreateSectionTable" line="28" stmtstart="2856" stmtend="2984" sqlhandle="0x030005005611575922a96e01ccad000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
SELECT @nTableIndex = Max(DataTableIndex) + 1 FROM SectionTable    </frame>
    <frame procname="CopySectionInt" line="118" stmtstart="9900" stmtend="10098" sqlhandle="0x030005001e33f860a2a96e01ccad000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
EXEC CreateSectionTable @SectionId, '', '', ''

    /* копирование в него структуры столбцов */    </frame>
    <frame procname="CopyForm" line="73" stmtstart="6408" stmtend="6530" sqlhandle="0x03000500acea0f5f7ea96e01ccad000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
EXEC CopySectionInt @SectionID, @FormId, null, null    </frame>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
Proc [Database Id = 5 Object Id = 1594878636]   </inputbuf>
  </process>
  <process id="process10ff03d498" taskpriority="0" logused="26216496" waitresource="PAGE: 5:1:23196243 " waittime="3894" ownerId="61920617" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2022-06-21T05:40:34.813" XDES="0x58a276d28" lockMode="S" schedulerid="6" kpid="4420" status="suspended" spid="66" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="1" lastbatchstarted="2022-06-21T05:40:34.817" lastbatchcompleted="2022-06-21T05:40:34.813" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.813" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="SQLSER" hostpid="6120" loginname="SS\Bo" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="61920617" currentdb="5" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673185824" clientoption2="128048">
   <executionStack>
    <frame procname="CreateSectionTable" line="28" stmtstart="2856" stmtend="2984" sqlhandle="0x030005005611575922a96e01ccad000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
SELECT @nTableIndex = Max(DataTableIndex) + 1 FROM SectionTable    </frame>
    <frame procname="CopySectionInt" line="118" stmtstart="9900" stmtend="10098" sqlhandle="0x030005001e33f860a2a96e01ccad000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
EXEC CreateSectionTable @SectionId, '', '', ''

    /* копирование в него структуры столбцов */    </frame>
    <frame procname="CopyForm" line="73" stmtstart="6408" stmtend="6530" sqlhandle="0x03000500acea0f5f7ea96e01ccad000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
EXEC CopySectionInt @SectionID, @FormId, null, null    </frame>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
Proc [Database Id = 5 Object Id = 1594878636]   </inputbuf>
  </process>
 </process-list>
 <resource-list>
  <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="24768207" dbid="5" subresource="FULL" objectname="SectionTable" id="locke19f0d280" mode="SIX" associatedObjectId="72057612168593408">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="process10ff03d498" mode="SIX" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="process10f2ea0188" mode="S" requestType="wait" />
   </waiter-list>
  </pagelock>
  <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="23196243" dbid="5" subresource="FULL" objectname="SectionTable" id="locke4b2da480" mode="SIX" associatedObjectId="72057612168593408">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="process10f2ea0188" mode="SIX" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="process10ff03d498" mode="S" requestType="wait" />
   </waiter-list>
  </pagelock>
 </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

This is what the form copying procedure itself looks like (all the inputs, except the first parameter, are the same for the two processes.
For example, process1 = CopyForm (12345, 12, 35), process2 = CopyForm (54321, 12, 35)):

Here is the code itself with the procedures:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CopyForm](@FormId as uniqueidentifier, @SrcFormId as uniqueidentifier, @DestFormTypeId as uniqueidentifier)
AS
BEGIN
    /* Here we declare the variables */

    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF

    /*code to create a new form */

    DECLARE cr CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR 
        SELECT ObjectID FROM SectionTable 
            WHERE Form = @SrcFormId 
            ORDER BY OrderNum desc
    OPEN cr
    FETCH NEXT FROM cr INTO @SectionID
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
        EXEC CopySectionInt @SectionID, @FormId, null, null
        FETCH NEXT FROM cr INTO @SectionID
    END
    CLOSE cr
    DEALLOCATE cr

END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CopySectionInt]( 
    @SrcSectionId as uniqueidentifier, 
    @DestFormId as uniqueidentifier, 
    @PrevSectId as uniqueidentifier, 
    @SectionId uniqueidentifier )
AS
BEGIN
    /* Here we declare the variables */ 
    
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF @SectionId IS NULL SELECT @SectionId = newid()

    IF @PrevSectId IS NULL 
        SET @nSectionNumber = 1
    ELSE
        SELECT @nSectionNumber = OrderNum + 1 FROM SectionTable WHERE ObjectID = @PrevSectId

    /* Here we create a new section */

    EXEC CreateSectionTable @SectionId
    
    /* remaining code  */
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateSectionTable]( @argObjectID uniqueidentifier )
AS
BEGIN
    /* Here we declare the variables */

    SELECT @nSectionNumber = OrderNum  FROM SectionTable WHERE ObjectID = @argObjectID

    SELECT @nTableIndex = Max(DataTableIndex) + 1 FROM SectionTable 
    SET @nTableIndex = ISNULL( @nTableIndex, 1 )
    
    UPDATE SectionTable SET DataTableIndex = @nTableIndex, OrderNum = @nSectionNumber WHERE ObjectID = @argObjectID

END
GO
```

I don't understand how these two processes are blocking each other if they are both accessing the same resource? And how can I fix this error?
Would blocking the CopyForm procedure with sp_getapplock help me in this case ? Or is there a way to solve the problem without blocking?

Comment: Because accessing the same resource the deadlock occurs, I suggest you to read about 
[Deadlock 1](https://www.sqlshack.com/understanding-the-deadlock-definition-in-sql-server/#:~:text=In%20terms%20of%20SQL%20Server,others%20to%20release%20the%20resource.) [Deadlock 2](https://www.sqlshack.com/what-are-sql-server-deadlocks-and-how-to-monitor-them/)

Comment: In order to diagnose a deadlock, we need to see the relevant table **and index** definitions, and please share the query plan via https://pastetheplan.com. This question is not answerable otherwise

Comment: Apparently you have your BeginTran/Commit transaction management done in your C# application. Easiest fix for this particular deadlock would be to use hints on the FROM clause on the cursor SELECT like this: `SELECT ObjectID FROM SectionTable WITH(UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK, SERIALIZABLE). . .` which will force serial (one after the other) execution of the SELECT on matching `Form = @SrcFormId` by concurrent execution of the sp. Generally `UPDLOCK` hint is a very cheap way to resolve deadlocks by serializing (i.e. blocking) concurrent reads/SELECTs on matching (the same) rows by two or more connections.

Comment: The entire point of these procedures is unclear. You are only doing a single `UPDATE` by the end of it, this could all be in one statement. Are there other missing statements here? A cursor is the slowest way to make queries by far, and therefore far more likely to cause a deadlock.